# Meteor: Bootstrap Modal breaks when handlebars values change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, meteor

I'm making a modal to handle payments, and I want to use some handlebars helpers to do form validation.

Here's the html:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="paymentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="paymentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="paymentModalForm" class="form-horizontal">
                    ...
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                            <!-- this session helper is a go-between with Session -->
                            <button {{session 'paymentFormInputsValid'}} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Make Payment
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the backing js:

```js
Template.paymentModal.events({
    'keyup .paymentFormInput': function(e, t) {
        var valid = t.findAll('.paymentFormInput').every(function(item) {
            return !!item.value.trim();
        });
        Session.set('paymentFormInputsValid', valid ? '': 'disabled');
    }
});
```

`paymentFormInputsValid` is set correctly, but when that `keyup` event happens, the modal disappears, and the black `.modal-backdrop` remains and doesn't allow any changes. It simply locks the user out and the page has to be refreshed.

Also, I previously had the button with more semantic handlebars, like this:

```html
<button {{#unless session 'paymentFormInputsValid'}}disabled{{/unless}}
    type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Make Payment
</button>
```

but that broke the submit button, and made it display like this:

[image]

Very broken.

How can I get modals to play nice with handlebars? Should I just go with a different strategy for this form?

Thanks in advance!

### Update

I now have this solution cobbled together. The template being inserted to my modal:

```html
<template name="paymentModalButton">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{paymentFormInputsValid}}>
        Make Payment
    </button>
</template>

<!-- In the appropriate place -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
        {{> paymentModalButton}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**But**, this still can't handle handlebars `{{#if}}` blocks, such as the one I *wanted* to use:

```
{{#unless session 'paymentFormInputsValid'}}disabled{{/unless}}
```

This still breaks the button rendering. It would be easier and more semantic to have this behavior, so if anyone can figure it out that would be delightful.

### Update

I dug into the `Elements`, and here's what that button looks like.

```
<button <!--data:8trm3tvlatwn9qaw9--=""> type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"&gt;
    Make Payment
</button>
```

Frankly I can't make any sense of that and why it's breaking. It's being generated from this, which is valid and works in other contexts:

```
<button {{#unless session 'paymentFormInputsValid'}}disabled{{/unless}} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Make Payment
</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try using {{#constant}} blocks

Comment: I'm looking into this now, hadn't thought of it!

Comment: While not a direct solution, you may consider using [Crater modals](http://code.subhog.com/crater#overlay) instead, they are designed to work better with Meteor.

Comment: @HubertOG, I think that's a cool library, but I have everything in bootstrap already and I want to keep appearance consistent. If I was just starting my layout I'd probably use Crater.

Comment: @pahan, the `{{#constant}}` blocks cause the modal markup to get broken up into pieces, so some of it rendered on the parent page instead of in the modal. Doing constants around the whole thing would defeat the purpose since I'm trying to get reactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="paymentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="paymentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                 {{> someOtherTemplate}}
```

It's a hack until the new blaze UI comes out.

The reason it fails is because as soon as the template changed, the entire template is redrawn, but the twitter bootstrap code is not applied.

Comment: Any thoughts on the `{{unless}}` block breaking up the html and causing the button to render strangely?

Comment: @blaineh Post what the DOM looks like for that broken button. Someone else had a similar issue with template helpers inside elements.

Comment: Alright, I've added that button's DOM. Can you make any sense about why that's happening?

Comment: @blaineh The `<!--data:8trm3tvlatwn9qaw9--="">` is exactly the same issue the other person had. I don't have the link to the question, but this issue is supposedly fixed with the new blaze UI, per someones response.

Comment: Alright, in the mean time I will keep any hacks necessary!

Comment: Hey, I've had a similar problem at a later stage that is happening for a different reason, check it out if you could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439172/meteor-modal-is-disappearing-and-locking-out-the-user

Comment: Blaze is out with meteor 0.8.3, but the modal is still broken inside the template. any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using Bootstrap modal's with Meteor's Spark rendering engine:
http://modal-example.meteor.com/

Source:
https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example

As @BradM points out, this kind of thing hopefully won't be an issue once Blaze (Meteor's new rendering engine) is released.

Comment: alanning, this is really cool! Can it do things like display forms though? Would I just declare the `message` property of a `dialog` to be something like a `Template.template()`?

Comment: A better question to ask is if bootbox will still work if any dialogs have changing handlebars in them?

Comment: It can definitely display forms; click a user's name to see the Manage Permissions form.  Basically form template is always included in parent template so reactivity works, but is hidden until wanted.  Session var is used to identify target user id. I populate form data in "Template.editRolesForm.rendered" to handle changing data since reactivity causes templates to re-render. Be sure to check the source for details.

Comment: I was absent-minded when I asked about them displaying forms, what I really meant was *templates*. See my other question about this, I've been having trouble getting them to cooperate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418592/bootboxjs-how-to-render-a-meteor-template-as-dialog-body