# Meteor: trying to add bootstrap classes with handlebars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to toggle the [Bootstrap `has-success` form validation state](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) with handlebars, like so:

```html
<!-- this is inside a modal dialog -->
<div class="form-group {{> paymentFormAmountValidate}}">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control paymentFormInput"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<template name="paymentFormAmountValidate">
    {{session "paymentFormAmountValidate"}}
</template>
```

(I've removed irrelevant markup from that stuff).

I removed the `{{session}}` helper into a different template because of the advice given in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306174/meteor-bootstrap-modal-breaks-when-handlebars-values-change).

I **know** that `{{session}}` helper is returning the right thing, `'has-success'`, because I've checked it thoroughly.

Here's what that `form-group` looks like in the `Elements` (when I copied it as html):

```
<div class="form-group &lt;!--label:Fv2nPkQeMCJEEuJ9p--&gt;">
    ...
</div>
```

Again, this is all happening within a modal, and that's what I suspect is causing all these problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306174/meteor-bootstrap-modal-breaks-when-handlebars-values-change/22307310?noredirect=1#comment33943417_22307310  Supposedly fixed with meteor ui. There is some issue with putting template helpers inside element attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was include more of the the actual html in the shared template. Using a `{{> template}}` style helper inside the `class` property wasn't working, so I changed it to this:

```html
<!-- This is in the modal template -->
{{> paymentFormAmount}}

<!-- This is obviously its own template -->
<template name="paymentFormAmount">
    <div class="form-group {{session 'paymentFormAmountValidate'}}">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Amount</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control paymentFormInput" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now it works great. Technically still a bit of a hack, but hey, it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want your text escaped, wrap with triple {{{ }}}

Comment: This is a Meteor bug.