# Meteor: bootbox seems to have erased all of my bootstrap files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less, bootbox

I have the following error:

```
input:26:1: Less compiler error: '/packages/bootstrap3-less/lib/less/variables.lessimport' wasn't found
```

This is confusing for two reasons.

- I don't know where this `input` file is. I include `variables.less` in `index.less` like this:

```css
@import "/packages/bootstrap3-less/lib/less/variables.lessimport";
```

which is technically on line **27**, not 26. Maybe I'm being crazy.

- I've checked that directory, that file is there, but it's **empty**.

They're **all** empty. All of the files under the `bootstrap3-less` directory are just cleaned out. (Well, most of them. Some of the json files and build files still have things in them, but all the good stuff is gone.)

I was using [this bootstrap less packaging](https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less) which looks like it has changed since I originally installed it.

This happened after installing [the bootboxjs meteor package](https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-bootboxjs) which I was very excited about. I installed it as it recommended:

```
mrt add bootboxjs
```

I have removed bootbox, but the damage to my bootstrap package is done.

What happened? How can I intelligently undo the damage? Should I just reinstall the `bootstrap3-less` package?

Also, **how can I keep this from happening again**?? I still want to install `bootboxjs`, since my modals aren't playing nice with changing handlebars ([Meteor: Bootstrap Modal breaks when handlebars values change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306174/meteor-bootstrap-modal-breaks-when-handlebars-values-change)) How should I intelligently install it? Should I maintain it as a local package?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem a week ago. When you add a package using `mrt` it automatically updates all of your other packages (good feature?). So when you added bootboxjs, it updated your bootstrap3-less package to use their new naming scheme, which is `*.import.less` rather than `*.lessimport`.

In order to fix this you have to update your references to any bootstrap related less files to `*.import.less`.

I would recommend just going back through your bootstrap configuration and making sure everything is as it should be according to their new [docs](https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less#how-to-install).

Comment: You nailed it. I reinstalled `bootstrap3-less`. Then bootbox was throwing off the bootstrap display, so I installed it locally and it works like a dream!