# How can I load in a bootbox a custom element with javascript methods attached?

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootbox

I want to use crop and resize images inside a bootbox. To achieve this, I use [Cropper](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).

Based on [the examples of Cropper](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/#examples), I should instantiate the cropper object in my bootbox when it is displayed and get rid of it when it is closed.

Is it possible or should I use a regular bootstrap modal?

Could I, for instance, add a `script` tag in the bootbox `message` in order to do the job there? That would be dirty, and before I commit into this, I wanted to check for more clean/elegant approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pattern for using bootbox custom dialogs is to write:

```
message: "<div id='dialogAnchor'></div>"
```

in the bootbox dialog definition and follow that up (*after* you create the bootbox) with

```
Blaze.render(Template.myDialog,$("#dialogAnchor")[0])
```

to embed my template into the bootbox dialog directly. This makes managing the contents of the bootbox much, much simpler. I haven't used cropper but assuming you can use it in a normal template then you can use the aforementioned pattern to get that template into a bootbox.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to render a template using spacebars (e.g.`{{> myTemplate}}`) helper but it didn't work. Your way works and is indeed much, much simpler :-). I validate the answer but please, put the HTML in the message key under quotes (it isn't correct as-is) and specify that your `Blaze.render` must be executed just after the `bootbox.dialog` function, but outside it.