# Open modal window based on value of reactive var in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a form

```
<template name="form">
  {{#autoForm id="afUpdateDemo" type=formType collection="Items" doc=selectedDoc autosave=autoSaveMode}}
    {{> afQuickField name="title"}}
    {{#unless autoSaveMode}}
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="{{disableButtons}}">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" disabled="{{disableButtons}}">Reset Form</button>
      </div>
    {{/unless}}
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

I want this form to open in a modal window. So the modal should be active if `selectedDoc` is not null. How can I do this? In the bootstrap doc, they only show how to activate a modal window through a link.

I have also found https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/autoform-modals but it will also only get active through a link.

Comment: you will need an `autorun` to listen for the reactive var and when ever it's `true` open the modal or close :)

Answer (score 0):

The [mizzao:bootboxjs](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/bootboxjs) package gives you this ability very directly from code.

```
if ( selectedDoc ) bootbox.dialog({
  .. your dialog definitions here
});
```

Comment: But where can I define my autoform? I was thinking of doing it directly in the template as `{{#if selectedDoc}}<div class="modal">{{#autoform ....{{/if}}`

Comment: Fortunately I've already answered that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27436504/2805154) ;)